# Write on a canvas with background-image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fonts

So I am trying to build a Meme-Creator. You already can upload the pics as the background-img from the canvas. Now I am trying to do the Meme font but it isnt really working. However it is creating a big gap in the picture. Thanks for your help and attention! :D

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("meme-canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;

function readImage() {
  if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
    var FR = new FileReader();
    FR.onload = function(e) {
      var img = new Image();
      img.addEventListener("load", function() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      });
      img.src = e.target.result;
    };
    FR.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
  }
}

function Text() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

  var textT = document.getElementById("top-text").value;
  var textB = document.getElementById("bottom-text").value;

  ctx.font = "60px Impact";
  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  ctx.strokeText(textT, 10, 65);
  ctx.strokeText(textB, 10, 400);
}

document.getElementById("image-input").addEventListener("change", readImage, false);
```

```html
<input type="file" id="image-input" accept="image/*">
<input type="text" id="top-text" oninput="Text()">
<input type="text" id="bottom-text" oninput="Text()">

<canvas style="position: absolute; width: 400px; top: 100px; left: 10px;" id="meme-canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made a few changes to your script. because you need to draw the image several times I've written a function that draws the image. The canvas is cleared every time one of the 2 text input changes it's value, and every time you have to redraw everything.

Also textT and textB can be declared only once. You don't need to declare them in the Text function.

I need to use the font size (60) more than once, so I've made a variable `fontSize = 60`

Since you don't know the size of your canvas ( depends on the size of the uploaded image ) you need to calculate the position for the bottom text  `textB = height - fontSize/2` where height is the height of the canvas: `height = canvas.height = img.height;`

I hope it's useful.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("meme-canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var width = (canvas.width = 400);
var height = (canvas.height = 400);
var fontSize = 60;
var img = new Image();

var textT = document.getElementById("top-text");
var textB = document.getElementById("bottom-text");

function readImage() {
  if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
    var FR = new FileReader();
    FR.onload = function(e) {
      img.addEventListener("load", function() {
        width = canvas.width = img.width;
        height = canvas.height = img.height;
        drawImage();
      });
      img.src = e.target.result;
    };
    FR.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
  }
}

function drawImage() {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}

function Text() {
  ctx.font = fontSize + "px Impact";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

  drawImage();
  ctx.strokeText(textT.value, width / 2, 65);
  ctx.strokeText(textB.value, width / 2, height - fontSize/2);
}

document
  .getElementById("image-input")
  .addEventListener("change", readImage, false);

textT.addEventListener("input", Text);
textB.addEventListener("input", Text);
```

```css
canvas{position: absolute; left: 10px; top:60px;border:1px solid #d9d9d9;}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="image-input" accept="image/*">
<input type="text" id="top-text" />
<input type="text" id="bottom-text" />

<canvas style="" id="meme-canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

A few of the issues I encountered:

- If you change the size of the canvas you should not use the variables, because those wont be correct, or you will need to keep track of them
- If you do clearRect you have to be aware what are you clearing and re-draw it.
- The font did not look too clear so I added a white shadow for better contrast
- The bottom text needed to be relative to the canvas height

Here is the code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("meme-canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img = new Image();

function readImage() {
  if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
    var FR = new FileReader();
    FR.onload = function(e) {
      img.addEventListener("load", function() {
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        draw();
      });
      img.src = e.target.result;
    };
    FR.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
  }
}

function draw() {
  var textT = document.getElementById("top-text").value;
  var textB = document.getElementById("bottom-text").value;

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.font = "60px Impact";
  ctx.shadowColor = "white" 
  ctx.shadowOffsetX = ctx.shadowOffsetY = 2
  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  if (img) ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  ctx.strokeText(textT, 10, 45);
  ctx.strokeText(textB, 10, canvas.height -10);
}

document.getElementById("image-input")
        .addEventListener("change", readImage, false);
```

```html
<input type="file" id="image-input" accept="image/*"><br>
<input type="text" id="top-text" placeholder="Top text" oninput="draw()"><br>
<input type="text" id="bottom-text" placeholder="Bottom text" oninput="draw()"><br>

<canvas  id="meme-canvas"></canvas>
```